# Unintelligible behavior when overlapping scroll events and wheel events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

1. 

```js
window.addEventListener("wheel",function(){
  console.log("wheel");
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
    console.log("scroll");
  });
})
```

When the mouse wheel is operated for the first time, I think only the "wheel" is displayed and the `window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){...})` only needs to be registered. However, looking at the output, the "wheel" and "scroll" are output at the same time.

2.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
  console.log("scroll");
  
  window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e){
    console.log("wheel");
  });
});
```

When the mouse wheel is operated for the first time, only "scroll" is output as I expected. However, if it is operated once more, it is output in the order of "wheel" "scroll". Why is the wheel output first?

Comment: don't put event listener inside another

Comment: _"Why is the wheel output first?"_ - Because without turning the wheel there's no scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand this better, i have provided,

```
<body style="height: 150vh;">
```

Please just press "downarrow" in the view and see the console., only "scroll" would be printed., --> it does not trigger wheel,

But if you use "Mouse wheel" to scroll, you will see both "wheel" and "scroll" as output in console.,

**More info:**

**scroll**
Fires when the user scrolls an element by any means (arrow keys, scrollbar or mouse wheel). You cannot prevent the scrolling.

**Wheel**
Fires when the user uses the mouse wheel. You can prevent this event’s default. Note that the page does not have to scroll in order to fire this event.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
  console.log("scroll");}); 

  window.addEventListener("wheel",function(){
    console.log("wheel");});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 150vh;">
  <h1>test</h1>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```